# SOLID and multiple inheritance

Tags: multiple-inheritance, solid-principles

I was thinking about languages that allow multiple inheritance like Python. How does SOLID apply to these languages?

It is often claimed that languages that allow multiple inheritance don't need interfaces. But what about type hinting?

If I define my method like this, I still have a hard dependency.
Therefor the Open closed principle cannot be applied, unless I extend a new class on the base class.

Why would I bother about a possible implementation someone wrote years ago and I want to be completely separated from that code by creating a new instance.

```
public function test(MyConcreteDependency $test){}
```

Is it true that interface based languages are cleaner for programming SOLID?

Comment: There are too many different questions here, and SOLID alone is five things. It would take a book with several chapters to cover all of this.

Comment: I think it is possible to summarize it.

Comment: I suppose they say that "languages that allow multiple inheritance don't need interfaces" because you can use a class as a type (and I assume you can use abstract classes) so child classes can kind of implement those parent base types (e.g. you can usually implement multiple interfaces, which is like multiple inheritance - in that the classes are of that type).